# Can Snow Leopard sync with Google's Exchange sync for iCal/AddressBook

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, exchange, google-sync

Has anyone tested Snow Leopard's exchange support with [Google's Exchange sync?](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33322)

Does it work for iCal and/or contacts? Will it sync contact groups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not since Google's Exchange sync uses ActiveSync while Snow Leopard uses EWS.

Answer (score 3):

So far no luck with syncing through exchange. However, you can setup iCal and AddressBook to sync with Google using other techniques. In the preferences of either app, go to Accounts. In AddressBook you can enable synchronization with Google/Yahoo/MobileMe (even without an iPhone), in iCal you can add a Google account to synchronize the calendars with.

I'll keep searching for a way to sync using exchange, however khaihon's comment on Google's server using ActiveSync instead of EWS does not look promising

Answer (score 1):

To those asking how to force Address book to sync with Google, once it's set up click on the small 'sync' icon in the menu bar at the top right of the screen - it looks like it's just for MobileMe sync, but it's actually not - it will also sync your address book.

If you don't work out how to do this, by default it will sync every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Use iSync to force address book to sync.

Answer (score 0):

I Got ical to sync with Google Calendars with Caldav

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358

No Address Book tho.